# HTML async script with react SSR

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am developing an app with webpack/react/redux/node and have already implemented Server Side Rendering. Everything works so far, so I rather have a general question. I used webpack to bundle my JS files and also activated code splitting. Therefore I have two bundles:

- bundle.js (my Components and custom code)
- vendor.js (react/redux modules)

Now, as far as I know, when I place both of these in a normal `<script>` tag, the browser waits until the page and all resources are fully loaded to display anything. That way I lose the performance benefits of SSR, don't I? 
I mean the page still gets parsed by Web crawlers, e.g. google, but a user still has to wait for the page to be fully loaded, before seeing anything.

I think putting `async` in the script tag would solve the problem, e.g.:

```
<script async src='/vendor.js'></script>
<script async src='/bundle.js'></script>
```

However, with `async` in the tag, `vendor.js` will normally be finished loading after `bundle.js`, since it is a bigger file.

Is there something I got wrong or is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: I am actually interested in the premise of the question: if OP doesn't add `defer` for the script tags, does it defeat the purpose of SSR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the `defer` attribute on the scripts tags.

`async` scripts are parsed and executed as soon as the resource is downloaded while `defer` scripts are only executed when they appear in the markup.

The article [Prefer DEFER over ASYNC](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/prefer-defer-over-async/) cover this subject in depth.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use defer or async on files which doesn't impact the page parse lifecycle. For example analytics scripts.
You can check the difference here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

But for startup performance you will have to split your bundles further with those which will be required during startup and those which won't and then you can use 'async' or 'defer'. I would prefer using 'defer' on a big file.